# Fix corrupted utf8 nvarchar value that was inserted without N prefix

Tags: sql-server, collation, unicode, utf-8

Is it possible to restore the UTF8 data from a corrupted nvarchar, that was used without the `N` prefix?

For example, in the following snippet, I'd like `@n1_fixed` to have the correct value based on `@n1`:

```
declare
  @n1 nvarchar(10) = 'Ḿấxiḿứś',
  @n2 nvarchar(10) = N'Ḿấxiḿứś';

declare
  @n1_fixed nvarchar(10); -- somehow make it have the correct value, based on @n1

select iif(@n1_fixed = @n2, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not possible to recover the original value.

Character constants without the `N` prefix to denote national characters are translated according to the database default collation code page. In cases where no clear mapping exists for the source character, the value is changed to a fallback character. This fallback may be similar but different character or the value `?` when no alternate character exists.

You can observe this by casting the value as varbinary. Example with a `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` default database collation, which uses code page 1252:

```
DECLARE @n1 nvarchar(10) = 'Ḿấxiḿứś', @n2 nvarchar(10) = N'Ḿấxiḿứś';
SELECT 
      @n1 AS corrupted_string
    , CAST(@n1 AS varbinary(100)) AS corrupted_raw_value
    , @n2 AS correct_string
    , CAST(@n2 AS varbinary(100)) AS correct_raw_value;
GO
```

| corrupted_string | corrupted_raw_value | correct_string | correct_raw_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ??xi??s | 0x3F003F00780069003F003F007300 | Ḿấxiḿứś | 0x3E1EA51E780069003F1EE91E5B01 |

Results of same script with an `Albanian_100_CI_AS` database default collation shows the last character is correctly mapped due to the 1250 code page but characters changed to the '?' fallback are lost permanently like the previous example.

| corrupted_string | corrupted_raw_value | correct_string | correct_raw_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ??xi??ś | 0x3F003F00780069003F003F005B01 | Ḿấxiḿứś | 0x3E1EA51E780069003F1EE91E5B01 |